# Spring JCR to Latest jackrabbit integration

Tags: jackrabbit, jcr

I am using Jackrabbit 2.6.3 and want to integrate with the spring jcr for injecting the repository.

```
<bean id="repository"
        class="org.springmodules.jcr.jackrabbit.RepositoryFactoryBean">
        <!-- normal factory beans params -->
        <property name="configuration" value="classpath:/jackrabbit-repository.xml" />
        <!-- use the target folder which will be cleaned  -->
        <property name="homeDir" value="file:./tmp/repository" />
</bean>
```

But the spring jcr versions seems to be quite old and looking for very old jars it seems.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project xyz: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.test.xyq:war:2.4.2: The following artifacts could not be resolved: jsr170:jsr170:jar:1.0, jeceira:jeceira:jar:0.1.3, aparzev:doka:jar:0.1, aparzev:commons:jar:0.2, jug:jug-asl:jar:2.0.0: Failure to find jsr170:jsr170:jar:1.0 in nexus/content/groups/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of  has elapsed /nexus/content/groups/ or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
```

Questions :

1. Can you point in any other way I can inject the repository ?
2. Is there any doc on how to integrate spring with JackRabbit.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a blog post [here](http://esofthead.com/jackrabbit-2-spring/). This example works well with latest jackrabbit 2.6.4 and Spring 3. You should get the right spring-jcr library, [this one](https://github.com/jbellmann/jcr-springextension) works for me